# OData Action Parameters is null in run time

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I was trying to define a Post OData Web API action.The parameter is a number.
I found an [article](https://damienbod.com/2014/06/16/web-api-and-odata-v4-crud-and-actions-part-3/)
And I followed as the article described, here is the source code:

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", model: GetModel());

    }

    private static Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<ThumbnailQueue>("ThumbnailQueues");
        builder.EntitySet<Document>("Documents");


        EntitySetConfiguration<ThumbnailQueue> thumbnailQueue = builder.EntitySet<ThumbnailQueue>("ThumbnailQueues");
        var action = thumbnailQueue.EntityType.Action("PostThumbnailQueue");
        action.Parameter<long>("DocumentSN");


        var postThumbnailQueue = thumbnailQueue.EntityType.Collection.Action("PostThumbnailQueue");
        postThumbnailQueue.Parameter<long>("DocumentSN");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Web API

```
public class ThumbnailQueuesController : ODataController
{
    private MarketingEntities db = new MarketingEntities();

    // POST: odata/ThumbnailQueues
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostThumbnailQueue(ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null) return BadRequest();

        var documentSN = (long)parameters["DocumentSN"];

        if (db.ThumbnailQueues.Any(t => t.DocumentSN == documentSN))
        {
            return BadRequest("Record already exists");
        }

        var myThumbnailQueue = new ThumbnailQueue();
        myThumbnailQueue.DocumentSN = documentSN;
        myThumbnailQueue.Status = 1;
        db.ThumbnailQueues.Add(myThumbnailQueue);


        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

I used Postman to test the function

[image]

But in the run time, the parameter is null, so I can not get documentSN from the parameter. I have troubleshoot this porblem for hours, could anybody help me to fix this problem? Many thanks~

Comment: Also don't forget to add the `Content-Type` HTTP header to `application/json` in your request, or the server won't know how to parse your body into the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following route for that: http://localhost:10076/odata/ThumbnailQueues/Default.PostThumbnailQueue

- ThumbnailQueues - entity set
- Default - default namespace
- PostThumbnailQueue - action

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful. I really appreciate it!